# Can I build two forms in FormType class in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this form class

```
class ProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

            ->add('name')
            ->add('class')
            ->add('age')
            ->add('parent')
     }
```

My problem is that I need two forms one for the backend where I need all the fields and one for the front end where I need few fields.

Do I need to create separate class for two forms or I can somehow put two forms in one class like suppose I don't want to display parent in frontend.

The problem is if i  display only few fields in template then those fields are set to null when i submit the form. So i need to remove from the class itself

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $options parameter.

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $profile, array('status' => 'backend'));
```

And in your buildForm :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name')
            ->add('class')
            ->add('age')
            ->add('parent');

    if($options['status'] == 'backend')
     {
        $builder->add('other1')
                ->add('other2');
     }
}
```

But it's quite a dirty solution, personally I would create two types.

Comment: It is not so dirty. But i am missing the default value in function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)

Answer (score 0):

Add default options too:

```
class ProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')
            ->add('class')
            ->add('age')
            ->add('parent');

        if($options['status'] == 'backend')
        {
            $builder->add('other1')
                ->add('other2');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Profile',
            'status' => 'frontend',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_profile';
    }
}
```

Now you are able to use the formtype without extra options or with extra options. In case without the default options will be used.